# i want to create a little drop down div on my hompage. when a button is clicked it show the drop down when clicked it goes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a button that when clicked will show will show a little drop down menu on the side like this one here: http://postimg.org/image/re433fr2l/ this the code that i already have:

**HTML**

```
<body background="http://s14.postimg.org/rpo7dneox/NEWW.png/>
    <div class="div3">
         <UL>
       <LI><a href="color.html">HOME</a></LI>
       <LI><a href="layout.html">ARTICLES</a></LI>
       <LI><a href="myform.html">CONTACT </a></LI>
         <UL>
    <div>
```

**CSS:**
    ul{
        font-family: impact; 
        font-size: 90px; 
        list-style: none;
    }

```
.div3{
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:0px solid cyan;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 570px;
}

a { 
    color:green;
}

a:hover{
    color:orange; 
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The code you present doesn't do anything that you are trying to achieve. What have you tried to solve *your problem*? Take a look at jQuery's click() and toggle() to toggle an element's visibility on click.

Comment: Doing this with jQuery is not to hard, so please learn before making questions

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltbodn0j/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu-toggle > button").click(function() {
        $(".menu-toggle > ul").toggle();
    });
});
```

Which translates to: if a user clicks the button -> toggle (show/hide) the list.

However, this is a very basic question so I advise you to follow an introductory tutorial on JavaScript and jQuery rather than simply copy-pasting my answer.